# Modify jPaginate script to jump to top with each page turn?

Tags: jquery, pagination, jquery-pagination

I've integrated a pagination script to break up long text on a page using jPagination: http://web.enavu.com/js/jquery/jpaginate-jquery-pagination-system-plugin/

See an example here: http://harrisstern.com/who/beachcomberbackstory.html

I'm looking for a way to modify the code to move the focus of a page to the top with each page 'turn' (e.g. moving from 1 to 2, 2 to 3, etc).

I'm a javascript newbie, would appreciate any insight you can offer!

Thanks,
Tim
Philadelphia, PA

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on this for a while now.

Place this line of code in the jPaginate.js file.

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
```

It needs to go after

```
createPagination($(this).attr("title"));
```

on line 183

and after

```
createPagination(newcurr);
```

on lines 192 and 201

These lines are in the "// handle click on pagination" section. 
This tells each button to scroll to the top of the page, it also has a slight animation making it looks really nice.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1, just for everyone who wants to avoid **scrolling** and wants **jumping** to top after page turn with jpaginate. Replace BostonBB'ss line with 
`$('html, body').scrollTop(0);`

Answer (score 0):

Use the scroll function

```
window.scroll(0, 0);
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GqgNc/)